# STM32H7 SDMMC1 stuck at Initializing phase

Tags: c, stm32, hal

I'm trying to make HAL's SDMMC1 work and didnt get any response in registers ( looking at it in KEIL's debug mode, registers just dont even toggle any bits) , also cant see any tries of Initialize MMC in oscillograph ( clock ,cmd and data line doesnt toggle as well).

Im Initializing MMC:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init(void)
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  while (1)
  {
    if (UserRxBufferFS[0] == 0x97)   // GOT command for emmc
     {  
      UserRxBufferFS[0] = 0;
      SDMMC1->POWER = 1; //check the power register( doesnt change in debug mode, why?)
      MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init();
      SDMMC_PowerState_ON(&hmmc2); // check the power register with HAL( doesnt change aswell)
      SDMMC_SendCommand(&hmmc2, 0); // checking cmd line, nothing happens in oscillo
      }
  }
static void MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init(void)
{
  hmmc1.Instance = SDMMC1;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hmmc1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hmmc1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockDiv = 0;
}
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 80;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

I know that to make mmc/sd card (their protocols pretty same) work we need to send a lot of cmd sequences, i have accomplished it earlier with soft mmc(sdio) realization, now i need speed for reading mmc and hardware can help me with it, but im stuck from the beginning, HAL realization and direct registers access just doesnt react on anyhting at all

Update. My RCC config:
[image: RCC HAL]

Update2. stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.h HAL generated (__HAL_RCC_C1_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE()  isnt active):
[image: rcc.h]

Comment: You said registers don't react to bit toggles - if they're all zero, you haven't provided the clock to the peripheral (in RCC).

Comment: @Ilya i have updated question with my rcc screenshot. i have HSE enabled

Comment: I agree it sounds like the peripheral isn't getting a clock signal.
Are you able to use STM32Cube to generate the init function for this? Should look like `MX_SDMMC_Init()`. I'd try generating that then calling it directly to see if it initializes the clock right.
If that's not possible, try calling [__HAL_RCC_C1_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE()](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32h7xx_hal_driver/blob/6dd7f0e35c80b6e46ab7b77c972d2e785054d7c6/Inc/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.h).

Comment: @GandhiGandhi HAL doesnt generate anything that looks like HAL_RCC_C1_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE(). All it generates relating to SDMMC is `static void MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init(void)` which is shown above. i have updated question with `HAL_RCC_C1_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE()`  screenshot , somehow its not active by default and how to enable it? :/

Comment: Hm. Try [__HAL_RCC_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32h7xx_hal_driver/blob/6dd7f0e35c80b6e46ab7b77c972d2e785054d7c6/Inc/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.h#L862C9-L862C36) instead. These ST HAL headers have ifdef guards like this to support different chips in the same family with different features, and I had to guess which chip.

Comment: @KlimDuda What I was saying is that you don't provide clock to SDMMC peripheral, it seems. The controls for it are in RCC. Usually there is a HAL function that can do it for you (discussed in other comments and answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things that I think might be causing init problems.

1. There should be some sort of RCC macro call to enable the clock to the peripheral. @Ilya saw this in the comments
2. I think there's a SDMMC_Init() call missing.
3. The code snippet switches between using `hmmc1` and `hmmc2`. I assume its only trying to work with one SDMMC instance at a time right?

After that, I think your SDMMC initialization code should look something like this.

```
// Enable the clock to the peripheral. I'm not sure if this is the right RCC macro though
__HAL_RCC_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE();
// initializes hmmc1 structure with configuration from STM32Cube
MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init();
// initializes the SMMC1 hardware peripheral with the config set above
SDMMC_Init(&hmmc1.Instance, &hmmc1.Init);
// Try the rest of your code here that works with the SDMMC registers
SDMMC_PowerState_ON(&hmmc1)
//....
```

I'm getting this info mostly from the doc in the HAL driver here: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32h7xx_hal_driver/blob/6dd7f0e35c80b6e46ab7b77c972d2e785054d7c6/Src/stm32h7xx_ll_sdmmc.c#L59-L71 . I don't have the hardware so I don't know if it will work. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your help, i m having problems with hmmc instances, for exmaple  for     SDMMC_PowerState_ON(&hmmc1); it shows me error "incompitable pointer types passing "MMC_HandleTypeDef *' to parameter of type SDMMC_TypeDef *'  while MMC_HandleTypeDef hmmc1; works fine with SDMMC_Init(hmmc1.Instance, hmmc1.Init); how can i use same hmm1 instance for SDMMC_PowerState_ON();?

Comment: Try `SDMMC_PowerState_ON(&hmmc1.Instance)` instead

Comment: Also it might help you to keep in mind this code is mixing ST HAL and LL libraries which is probably asking for trouble in the long run of maintaining this program. I'm just trying to help get your example up and running. Its the best I can do. It might help you out to configure STM32CUBE to generate LL code thttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972831/how-to-use-ll-low-level-drivers-in-cubemx-stm32